# Menorah Placement

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia

I am living in a college dorm where we are not allowed to have open flames in our dorm. However, we are allowed to have flames in our floor lounge (with no windows). Should I light my Chanukah candles in the lounge? If not, what should I do?

Comment: "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi."

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. It might help to ask your campus rabbi through e.g., Chabad, JLIC, as he is closest to the specifics of the situation and best able to help. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: A good place to look for sources: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Placement_of_the_Chanukah_Candles#Lighting_in_Yeshiva But it's always better to consult your rabbi.